# WCF vs. Web API for Windows 8 store apps

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

I suggested we migrate from WCF to Web API due to it being easier to implement and got shot down pretty hard. Here were the objections raised:

- WebAPI is just made for rails converts
- We have no need for REST or 3rd party open source support, Windows 8 Store Apps with Microsoft backend.
- WCF over net.tcp is "MUCH" faster and less overhead than HTTP(S)+XML or JSON

The end comment was "I cannot think of a single advantage of using Web API over WCF.

Funny, my last job at a big MS tech based enterprise changed from WCF to Web API and dev productivity skyrocketed, lots of bugs disappeared and we never had any performance problems, but I don't want to just say that, I want to respond with facts to his points. How would you respond?

Comment: As I know there is no other implementation of net.tcp other than by Microsoft in .NET. By using it you narrow your service's clients down drastically. But it depends on your particular use case.

Comment: From my experience it's really easy to implement. You don't need configuration at all. Just deploy on a web server and you're ready to go. With Web API 2.1 routing became pretty fluent and flexible. You can add RCP/MVC style methods in addition to HTTP verbs. And many more such as easy dependency injection, free caching, etc.

Comment: Will this/these products have android/ios/some other os implementation?

Comment: The thought is that these apps will always be Windows 8 Store Apps, which are all on the Metro WinRT UI based on XAML. No JavaScript, no JSON, no need for REST.

Comment: Hopefully we get to do a web app soon then I can use Web API instead and use it to feed JSON to JS code in a browser.

Comment: How does he plan to get through firewalls using net.tcp?

Comment: I guess he thinks its all behind firewalls since these apps are all internal.

Comment: Lots of miss information here ,. I think you last shop was a REST shop .. net.tcp can talk through firewalls perfectly on port 80 just like rest /http  we do it all the time though mostly its outgoing /pull so you can use any port .   Never had any issues with bugs on WCF except for people with NO experience on it eg basic gotchas like low limits for DOS attacks or people who stuff around with fancy security . Stick with nettcp and basichttp and dont use namespaces for  smaller messages.

Answer (score 1):

[WCF or ASP.NET Web APIs? My two cents on the subject](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2012/03/05/wcf-or-aspnet-web-apis-my-two-cents-on-the-subject/):

> - If your intention is to create services that support special scenarios – one way messaging, message queues, duplex communication
>     etc, then you’re better of picking WCF
> - If you want to create services that can use fast transport channels when available, such as TCP, Named Pipes, or maybe even UDP (in WCF
>     4.5), and you also want to support HTTP when all other transports are unavailable, then you’re better off with WCF and using both SOAP-based
>     bindings and the WebHttp binding.
> - If you want to create resource-oriented services over HTTP that can use the full features of HTTP – define cache control for browsers,
>     versioning and concurrency using ETags, pass various content types
>     such as images, documents, HTML pages etc., use URI templates to
>     include Task URIs in your responses, then the new Web APIs are the
>     best choice for you.

The whole article is worth a read.

Comment: Id add if you do lots of small CRUD apps then REST is a natural fit if you do large complex projects then DDD/ SOA/ Services are a better fit.